# How to put a one two-dimensional array into another

Tags: java

The question is how do I put one two-dimensional array into another if I explain simply the meaning of this project is a self-constructed maze of room which I, as an amateur, cannot describe with due detail because
I don't know what details to add.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    static String[][] maze;
    public static String Room (int x)
    {
        // create random number 
        int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current ().nextInt (5, x + 1);
        maze = new String[randomNum][randomNum];
        for (int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < maze.length; j++) {
                //create the ROOM
                maze[i][j] = "c";
                maze[0][j] = "\u2014";
                maze[maze.length - 1][j] = "\u2014";
                maze[i][0] = "\u007c";
                maze[i][maze.length - 1] = "\u007c";
                maze[0][maze.length - 1] = "+";
                maze[maze.length - 1][0] = "+";
                maze[0][0] = "+";
                maze[maze.length - 1][maze.length - 1] = "+";
            }
        }

        return (Arrays.deepToString(maze)
            .replace("]", "\n")
            .replace("[[", " ")
            .replace("[", "")
            .replace(",", ""));
    }

    public static String Maze(int x) {
        int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current ().nextInt (40, x + 1);
        maze = new String[randomNum][randomNum];
        for (int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++) {
            // create the maze 
            for (int j = 0; j < maze.length; j++) {
                maze[i][j] = "r";
                maze[0][j] = "\u2014";
                maze[maze.length - 1][j] = "\u2014";
                maze[i][0] = "\u007c";
                maze[i][maze.length - 1] = "\u007c";
                maze[0][maze.length - 1] = "+";
                maze[maze.length - 1][0] = "+";
                maze[0][0] = "+";
                maze[maze.length - 1][maze.length - 1] = "+";
            }
        }
        return (Arrays.deepToString(maze)
                .replace("]", "\n")
                .replace ("[[", " ")
                .replace ("[", "")
                .replace (",", ""));
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) { 
        // just output   
        String a = Maze(40);
        String x = Room(10);
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do or what problem you are facing.  Since you say you are an amateur, don't try to put it in overly technical terms or even coding terms at all.  Describe, in plain language, what you are trying to do and what problem you are facing.    
EX: I am trying to create a maze of random height and width.  The problem is my maze doesn't have any entrances or exits.

Comment: I apologize if I give the impression of someone who resorts to abstract terminology, but this has more to do with the mother dialect, I will try to say very simply what I am trying to achieve. 
I'm trying to make a labyrinth that builds itself. 
Having a large area, I want to put other rooms inside, which are smaller, and build a labyrinth out of them.

Comment: It would appear that the maze function and the room function do exactly the same thing. If you call Maze(40) and then Room(10), the call to Room(10) will completely overwrite what was done in Maze(40).  Are you trying to make a maze with 40 rooms and have each room have 10 smaller rooms in them?

Comment: Yes it is, I know that the initialization of the rooms with the maze itself is identical just with this initialization was easier for me to separate the zones of work 

And yes, I'm trying to do exactly what you described.

Comment: Do you want all the rooms within the maze to be the same size?  Or can they be different sizes?

Comment: different sizes. I added random for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you need to change the room function to use a local string[][] instead of the static string[][] maze declared by the class and change your return statement to process that instead.

Then change your maze function to call the room function each loop instead of doing its own thing